# Enforce Single Contract for Two or more Modules

Tags: f#

Is there any supported means in F# that allows one to define something similar to an interface  that two or more modules can be required to implement? For example, suppose I define a collection of algorithms alg_1, alg_2, ...., alg_n and define then corresponding function values in module_a. Next, in module_b I also implement alg_1, alg_2, ..., alg_n (in a different way, perhaps for testing purposes). So, the "signatures" of module_a and module_b are exactly the same and I would like the same code to exercise the functions irrespective of whether module_a or module_b is in scope.

Using OO techniques/interfaces (in F#/C#/etc.) this is straightforward; what's the best way to handle this situation using functional techniques in F#? Is there a different way to think about the problem that would be more productive?

Comment: Maybe generate a signature file and use it for both files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define module signatures in F# using `.fsi` files, but you won't be able to choose between multiple implementations of the module at runtime, so this has only limited usability for selecting between implementations of the same abstract interface.

However, F# combines functional programming with object-oriented programming and it is perfectly fine to use concepts from both worlds when they are a good fit - so if you want to choose between algorithms at runtime, I think that interfaces provide the best solution.

Even with interfaces, you can still use very functional style. Say you have an interface:

```
type IAlgorithms =
  abstract Distance : float * float -> float
  abstract Compare : float * float -> bool
```

Your two modules can contain functions implementing the different functionality as usual. Then you can add a value that returns an implementation of the interface (and exposes the functionality in a reusable way):

```
module MyAlgorithms = 
  let distance a b = sqrt ((a - b) * (a - b))
  let compare a b = a < b

  let algorithms = 
    { new IAlgorithms with
        member x.Distance(a, b) = distance a b
        member x.Compare(a, b) = compare a b}
```

Here, I'm using object expression to implement the `IAlgorithms` interface - which is a little easier than wrapping everything in a class.

But it really depends on the concrete situation, so this approach might or might not work for you!

Comment: Thanks; I agree the approach you suggest has merit. However, it's really not optimal for my situation. The primary reason I want to use modules as described is to preclude the need to go through an object, even if it has no state. Being able to open a module and have all of the functions in scope targets my needs perfectly. I guess the answer then is that there's really nothing in F# that supports directly what I want to do (Since the CLR doesn't support the concept of a "static class adhering to a contract" this isn't really surprising)

Comment: @genericdeveloper I'm still not entirely sure what you need though - for example, do you want to switch between algorithms at runtime? (If no, you could just use shared `fsi` files to guarantee the compatibility.)

Comment: Yes, I would like to be able to switch at runtime, more-or-less like what you can do with the strategy pattern.